# Writing a tuples function that permutes all possible n-tuples

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I'm working towards a tuples function, which takes collections and a parameter n. The parameter designates the number of indices the generated vector should have. The function then permutes all possible n-tuples of the elements in the collection.

So far I've been trying to combine functions from tuples.core and math.combinatoris,
namely, tuples and permutations.

```
  (defn Tuples [& args]
        (combo/permutations (tuple args)))
```

Example)

input: (0,1) n=3

output: [[0,0,0] [0,0,1] [0,1,0] [1,0,0] [0,1,1] [1,1,0] [1,0,1] [1,1,1]]

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking for here.  Can you add some more context?  For example, sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [clojure.math.combinatorics/selections](http://clojure.github.io/math.combinatorics/#clojure.math.combinatorics/selections):

```
(require '[clojure.math.combinatorics :as c])

(c/selections [0 1] 3)
;=> ((0 0 0) (0 0 1) (0 1 0) (0 1 1) (1 0 0) (1 0 1) (1 1 0) (1 1 1))
```